# kafka binding to ipv6 port even though ipv4 address specified in config

Tags: apache-kafka

I am in a bit of a bind (pun intended).

I have a ubuntu server running kafka & zookeeper. This server has both ipv4 and ipv6 protocols installed.

In the server.properties file, I specified the host.name and advertised.host.name as my public ipv4 address.

When I start zookeeper and kafka, kafka still binds to ipv6 port.

```
$ netstat -l -t | grep 9092 
tcp6       0      0 ferozed-linux3.mydomain:9092 [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

The client machine from which I am running a producer in a MapReduce job, is an IPv4 machine. Due to the fact that the server is binding to an IPv6 interface, the client is unable to connect to it.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: For a solution using `server.properties` instead of env vars see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58664478/7613058

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from Andrey's answer, you can solve it just by adding an environment variable

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=True"
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you need the following:

`System.setProperty ("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");`

in the code, or

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = True`

in the web server startup script worked.

Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this is `kafka/bin/Kafka-run-class.sh`

```
KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=True"
```

And restart Kafka broker.