# Bind kafka to 0.0.0.0:9092

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have set up Kafka on my amazon ec2 machine running ubuntu-18 following this [blog plost](https://towardsdatascience.com/install-a-kafka-cluster-on-ubuntu-in-aws-17c951287284) and this is how it is exposing the ports.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      772/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1220/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3004            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1041/mongod         
tcp6       0      0 :::45827                :::*                    LISTEN      2059/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::9092                 :::*                    LISTEN      2136/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      2059/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::32851                :::*                    LISTEN      2136/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1220/sshd
```

how can I bind it to `0.0.0.0:9092`?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I bind it to 0.0.0.0:9092

`:::9092` should be all you need for binding on IPv6.

If you want to force IPv4, please refer [kafka binding to ipv6 port even though ipv4 address specified in config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533837/kafka-binding-to-ipv6-port-even-though-ipv4-address-specified-in-config)

---

---

You can also add this to server.properties to explicitly bind to all interfaces

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

But when set, you also need to set (and uncomment) `advertised.listeners` to the external interface address (IP or hostname) that clients should use to communicate to that server, as mentioned in the property file.

```
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
```

More details here if you need something more complex https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained

Comment: thank you @cricket_007, but unfortunately the kafka server was failing to start when i made the update. But there is a section in the blog post that you shared that saved my life.

Comment: getting this error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.

Comment: @MataPrasadChauhan This answer is for **listeners**, your error is for **advertised.listeners**

Comment: @OneCricketeer The error above is seen when ONLY the `listeners` is used, and `advertised.listeners` is still commented out, no idea why the error points to `advertisers.listeners`. Using `0.0.0.0` does not work, kafka fails to start.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell There is a default property in the source code, even if the config file is commented out. I never said to set `advertised.listeners` to a non-routable IP

Comment: ` I never said to set advertised.listeners to a non-routable IP` I think that's the disconnect here, we are not touching `advertised.listeners`. Setting `listeners` to your answer causes the failure with the error code above. As such the answer does not actually work as it is currently stated. If a change must ALSO be made to `advertised.listeners` for this to not fail, then the answer should include that.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Understood now. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this on aws ec2 running ubuntu 18, the blog post shared in the first answer provides detailed information on how to go about this kind of challenge. The main challenge was failing to get a broker connection from the machine.

What worked is to add your machines public DNS(ec2......com) to advertised listeners.
I made the edit in server.properties file and like

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://public DNS(ec2......com):9092
```